# How can I define a neighborhood (not only $\delta$ neighborhood) in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I define a neighborhood (not only $\delta$ neighborhood) of a point in $\mathbb R$.

**without using metric concept**.

According to rudin's definition which must be a open set.

Comment: If $\mathcal T $ is a topology on $\Bbb R $, a neighborhood of a point $a$ is any open set $U$ (that is $U\in \mathcal T $) containing $a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need *some* concept. If you don't want metric concept,  then you at the very least need topology. And in topology, rather than a metric, all you have available to work with is the collection of all subsets of $\Bbb R$ which we call "open".

In this context, a neighborhood of $x\in\Bbb R$ is simply any such open set which contains $x$.

Comment: A small clarification: in some books any set which contains an open set containing $x$ is called a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy exactly.In many undergrad books it is written.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right. With that convention, an open neighborhood is an open set containing the point, and a neighborhood is any set which contains an open neighborhood.